# PHP script downloads fine on Localhost but on live site outputs file

Tags: php, wordpress, file, download, output

Forgive me I'm a complete virgin at PHP, I'm writing a plugin for wordpress that allows someone to sell a code to a customer, inturn this customer then visits the site and enters that code in to a text box and hits submit. The php script then checks mysql for that code if it exists it will initiate a download, because its selling downloads(photos in a zip) it grabs a filename given on a server with NO extension then outputs it as the filename that it should be in the save as box for downloading, just as I finish the functionality of the code I then test it on a live site after first testing it local... Now this is the issue on the localhost (xampp) it starts the download and works fine on the live site it does this :

http://www.ctwo12.com/output.png

This is my code:

```
$fileonS = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/wp-content/plugins/photo_dwn_man/downloads/" .    $codeRResult;

//download file (NEEDS MORE LOOKING INTO THIS IS JUST THE BASICS)
header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=' . $codeOResult . '.zip');
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
header('Pragma: public');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($fileonS));
ob_clean();
flush();
readfile($fileonS);
exit;
```

Hoping you guys can help or point me in the right direction, please explain too as I'm here to learn not copy!

regards,
adam

Comment: I'm starting to think it could be related to an internal server setting on the live server if so I haven't a clue what it could be...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right so this is how I fixed it... I had to add the headers part to a separate PHP file and when the correct code is entered and submitted I called some JavaScript to load the PHP and pass some GET variables...

My separate file contains :

```
<?php
    $getcodeOResult = $_GET['gcor'];
    $getcodeRResult = $_GET['gcsr'];
    $fileonS = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/wp-content/plugins/photo_dwn_man/downloads/" . $getcodeRResult;
header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate"); // HTTP/1.1
    header("Expires: Sat, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT");
    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=' . $getcodeOResult . '.zip');
    header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
    header('Pragma: public');
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($fileonS));
    ob_clean();
    flush();
    readfile($fileonS);
?>
```

then the function that starts the download goes like this :

```
function startDownload() {
    // This function handles the download start
    // Get filename you want user to download by getting the contents of dB row that matches the user input
    $theCodeOfile = $GLOBALS['wpdb']->get_col( "SELECT dwn_file FROM wp_photodwnman WHERE dwn_code='" . $GLOBALS['userCode'] . "'");

    // Get the actual servers filename by getting the contents of dB row that matches the user input
    $theCodeRfile = $GLOBALS['wpdb']->get_col( "SELECT dwn_pseu FROM wp_photodwnman WHERE dwn_code='" . $GLOBALS['userCode'] . "'");

    // join both results into a string and not an array
    $codeOResult = join("", $theCodeOfile);
    $codeRResult = join("", $theCodeRfile);
    $GLOBALS['wpdb']->query( "UPDATE wp_photodwnman SET dwn_count=dwn_count+1 WHERE dwn_code='" . $GLOBALS['userCode'] . "'");
    // adds to variable the location and filename
    echo "<script>window.onload = function(){window.location.href='http://ctwo12photography.co.uk/wp-content/plugins/photo_dwn_man/dwnload.php?gcor=" . $codeOResult . "&gcsr=" . $codeRResult . "'};   </script>";
}
```

So I never got to the bottom of why it behaved this way but this provided a solution!

Answer (score 0):

This can be caused by a number of things. two of the most common causes are:

1. PHP is not enabled on your server
2. your code is using php short tags and the server has them turned off `<?` vs `<?php`

Comment: This is a plugin within wordpress, wordpress is written in php and as such I cant imagine that's the reason why, the script itself works and functions correctly but when it comes to a download on the local server its fine on the live server it outputs the file on screen in text but with all the wordpress template intact.

Comment: P.s. I'm using full php tags

Answer (score 0):

Check internal settings of your server & see if PHP is enabled. If it's enabled, then try re-configuring your server & php. If problem still persists, you should then check this on some friend's server where things are fine to see if problem is with your server or not.

Comment: Again as mentioned in other answer WORDPRESS is built with php if PHP was not enabled then WORDPRESS would not even work! nor would all the other parts of my plugin script, the issue is only on the downloading!